# How to set default sound chip in alsamixer? Or disable auto-mute in PulseAudio?

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa, pulseaudio, realtek

I would like to disable the auto-mute feature and tried to do so by deactivating it in `AlsaMixer`. Unfortunetaly, this does not work. The setting is being ignored.

When I start `AlsaMixer` it shows only two controls (Master and Capture), although I've already set "View" to "All":

[image: AlsaMixer default]

I think this is because the default sound chip is `PulseAudio`?!

This is what `AlsaMixer` shows me when I select a sound card:

[image: AlsaMixer default sound chip]

...when I change the sound card to `HDA Intel PCH` I have the whole control set that I am familiar with from my desktop computer:

[image]

Notice that sound chip now says `Realtek ALC293`, which is correct. However, the disabled Auto-Mute there is being ignored by any application.

How can I make Alsa use `Realtek ALC2293` by default? Or is there any way to disable auto-mute in PulseAudio (my system uses PulseAudio)?

I am using Manjaro (Arch Linux) with Kernel 4.7.7-1.

Comment: That control is implemented by the hardware. If PulseAudio does its own automuting, you have to disable it there.

Comment: I do not know if PulseAudio does auto-muting. At least I did not find any information nor setting for auto-muting in PulseAudio. However, it has to be either AlsaMixer that selects the PulseAudio chip and ignores the disabled auto-mute on `Realtek ALC293` or PulseAudio has its own auto-mute option, because auto-mute is still working.

Comment: Could you describe what exactly is auto muted in what situation? Pulseaudio already uses the Alsa hardware, and the *PulseAudio* "sound chip" only allows Alsa applications to use PulseAudio, it's not real hardware. So if you disabled the hardware auto-muting, then either this auto-muting works differently than you think, or something else auto-mutes (whatever it is that gets muted).

Comment: Whenever I launch applications like Mumble, TeamSpeak, Skype, IP phone software, and so on other applications get muted (like VLC Player, Amarok, Spotify, ...). I googled and found out that others solved this by deactivating auto-mute in `alsamixer`. However, this does not work for me. I thought this may be because of the PulseAudio chip (that virtual thing) being the default sound chip instead of the Realtek ALC293.

Comment: First step to debug: run `pavucontrol` and look what happens when you start a new application. In principle, pulseaudio should handle the "mixing" (several apps on one sink), and just forward the mixed stream to the ALSA driver, so ALSA auto-mute shouldn't have anything to do with it. But who knows ...